# Struggling to see why my tic tac toe minimax game is not picking the best move - python

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe, minimax

i am struggling to see how my minimax algorithm is not working. It cycles through all the best moves but it dosen't pick the best one and i can't figure out why. For example i can input 1 5 9 and win. sorry in advance if the solution is something simple
Here is the code.

```
board = {1: ' ', 2: ' ', 3: ' ',
         4: ' ', 5: ' ', 6: ' ',
         7: ' ', 8: ' ', 9: ' '}
win = False
turn = 1
depth = 1
nodeindex = 0
possibles= []
moves = []
depth = 0
targetdepth = 3
movesdone = []
#def minimax(moves, targetdepth, depth, turn, scores):


def checkForWin(mark):
    if board[1] == board[2] and board[1] == board[3] and board[1] == mark:
        return True
    elif (board[4] == board[5] and board[4] == board[6] and board[4] == mark):
        return True
    elif (board[7] == board[8] and board[7] == board[9] and board[7] == mark):
        return True
    elif (board[1] == board[4] and board[1] == board[7] and board[1] == mark):
        return True
    elif (board[2] == board[5] and board[2] == board[8] and board[2] == mark):
        return True
    elif (board[3] == board[6] and board[3] == board[9] and board[3] == mark):
        return True
    elif (board[1] == board[5] and board[1] == board[9] and board[1] == mark):
        return True
    elif (board[7] == board[5] and board[7] == board[3] and board[7] == mark):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def checkForWin2():
    if (board[1] == board[2] and board[1] == board[3] and board[1] != ' '):
        return True
    elif (board[4] == board[5] and board[4] == board[6] and board[4] != ' '):
        return True
    elif (board[7] == board[8] and board[7] == board[9] and board[7] != ' '):
        return True
    elif (board[1] == board[4] and board[1] == board[7] and board[1] != ' '):
        return True
    elif (board[2] == board[5] and board[2] == board[8] and board[2] != ' '):
        return True
    elif (board[3] == board[6] and board[3] == board[9] and board[3] != ' '):
        return True
    elif (board[1] == board[5] and board[1] == board[9] and board[1] != ' '):
        return True
    elif (board[7] == board[5] and board[7] == board[3] and board[7] != ' '):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def possiblemoves(board):
    y=0
    possibles.clear()
    for i in board:
        if board[i] == " ":
            possibles.append(i)
    return possibles


def botgo(possibles, mark):
    bestscore = -800
    bestmove = 0
    for key in board.keys():
        if (board[key] == ' '):
            board[key] = mark
            score = minimax(board,0,False)
            board[key] = ' '
            if(score > bestscore):
                bestscore = score
                bestmove = key
    insert(bestmove,mark='O')
    return
def printboard():
    print(board[1] + '|' + board[2] + '|' + board[3])
    print('-----')
    print(board[4] + '|' + board[5] + '|' + board[6])
    print('-----')
    print(board[7] + '|' + board[8] + '|' + board[9])

def start():
    turn = 1
    count = 0
    while count != 9:
        humango()
        printboard()
        possiblemoves(board)
        botgo(possibles, mark='O')
        printboard()
        count = count + 1
        
        #minimax(depth, possibles)

def spacefree(space):
    if board[space] == ' ':
        return True
    else:
        return False
def insert(space, mark):
    if spacefree(space):
        board[space]=mark
        if checkForWin(mark):
            if mark == 'X':
                printboard()
                print("human win")
                exit()
            else:
                printboard()
                print("BOT WIN")
                exit()
    else:
        print("cannot insert there!!!")
        space = int(input("Enter position"))
        insert(space, mark)
def checkdraw(board):
    if checkForWin2():
        return True
def humango():
    global turn
    space = int(input("Enter position"))
    insert(space, mark='X')
    turn = turn + 1
    printboard()

def minimax(board, depth, ismax):
    if checkForWin(mark='O'):
        return 1
    elif checkForWin(mark='X'):
        return -1
    elif checkdraw(board):
        return 0
    if ismax == True:
        bestscore = -800
        for key in board.keys():
            if (board[key] == ' '):
                board[key] = 'O'
                score = minimax(board, depth + 1, False)
                board[key] = ' '
                if (score > bestscore):
                    bestscore = score
                printboard()
        return bestscore
    else:
        bestscore = 800
        for key in board.keys():
            if (board[key] == ' '):
                board[key] = 'X'
                score = minimax(board, depth + 1, True)
                board[key] = ' '
                if (score < bestscore):
                    bestscore = score
        return bestscore


    
start()
```

sorry for the messy code, thank you in advance

Comment: CheckForWin and CheckForWin2 can be merged by passing an extra parameter.

Comment: When you make a recursive call like `minimax(board, depth + 1, False)`, are you expecting the `board` object to get copied? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are complicating things, it will be much easier for you to debug with less code to look at. I would first suggest that you use a list instead of a dict to simplify your code in this game: `board = [' ']*9`. All my suggestions/simplifications below are based on this representation.

**1..** Checking for win on a 1D board is super easy. First you create a variable with all the possible winning lines:

```
winning_lines = ([0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6])
```

Then you can loop through them with a loop:

```
def is_win(board, player):    
    for pos in winning_lines:
            if board[pos[0]] == board[pos[1]] == board[pos[2]] == player:
                return 1
```

**2..** Checking for draw is even simpler since you only need to check if there are empty spaces or not:

```
def is_draw(board):
    return 0 if ' ' in board else 1
```

**3..** You don't need the depth variable in this game since you always go to maximum depth, ending in win, draw or loss. The depth can be used to always chose the shortest path to winning if there are more than 1 path, or the longest path to loss. Then you need to add and subtract depth from your check_win return statements in the minimax loop.

**4..** You can get all the possible moves with list comprehension:

`possible_moves = [i for i in range(len(board)) if board[i] == ' ']`

**Debugging**

There are a few other clean ups to do, but to figure out why it gives the wrong answer you need to do some debugging. Does your win/draw/loss function work as you think it does, i.e. does it return the correct result for a known input board? Does it loop through all the possible moves? Print things in your minimax loop and see if it behaves as you would expect.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. After implementing it, the program suddenly started working! i can't explain how i did it; but it works!